# exec command with file descriptor

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

The below unix commands are working fine when I am executing it as a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Redirecting stdin using 'exec'.


exec 6<&0          # Link file descriptor #6 with stdin.
                   # Saves stdin.

exec < data-file   # stdin replaced by file "data-file"

read a1            # Reads first line of file "data-file".
read a2            # Reads second line of file "data-file."

echo
echo "Following lines read from file."
echo "-------------------------------"
echo $a1
echo $a2

echo; echo; echo

exec 0<&6 6<&-
#  Now restore stdin from fd #6, where it had been saved,
#+ and close fd #6 ( 6<&- ) to free it for other processes to use.
#
# <&6 6<&-    also works.

echo -n "Enter data  "
read b1  # Now "read" functions as expected, reading from normal stdin.
echo "Input read from stdin."
echo "----------------------"
echo "b1 = $b1"

echo

exit 0
```

But when I am executing the commands individually in the terminal, the below command is giving 'command not found' error:

```
exec < data-file
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you give the command `exec < file`, then the current bash shell will read its input from *file*, rather than std-in.

I assume what happens when you give the commands individually in the terminal is the exec command works correctly, and your current (interactive) bash shell starts reading `data-file` (rather than your keyboard). I guess that data-file doesn't contain bash commands, and therefore bash responds with command not found.

Comment: But when I am running it through shell script, then also my data-file doesn't contain any bash commands but still the script is running sucessfully, it don't understand this behaviour.

Comment: If you are running a shell script, bash is reading the commands it executes from the file containing the shell script. When you run in a terminal, bash is running in interactive mode, and reading the commands from std-in. Therefore if you use the `exec <` command in a script it changes the std-in which is read by commands in the script file. If you use `exec <` in an interactive shell (like the terminal) bash reads the commands  from whatever you have redirected it from, rather than the keyboard

Comment: but as you said earlier , exec will try to execute whatever commands are in the file , which in this case there is only data, so by that means it should give error while running in shell script, ryt?

Comment: @Pankaj: When the shell executes a script the shell reads commands from the script, which _is not standard input_. When you execute `exec <somefile` in a script you change standard input (file descriptor 0), not the file descscriptor of the script. When you run `exec <somefile` interactively you have just switched the shell from reading commands from the termal to reading them from that file.